# Losing file properties on resumeable upload Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I'm running into trouble when using Google Cloud storage's resume-able upload for music and video files. Namely that certain properties are lost when uploaded and then downloaded back from the bucket.

Details: (original file on the left, downloaded file on the right)
[image: (original file on the left, downloaded file on the right)]

General: (original file on the left, downloaded file on the right)[image: General]

This isn't necessarily a problem for audio but it is for video as the browser now won't playback it in-browser.

The process for uploading is much the same as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31261552/google-cloud-storage-resumable-upload-initiate-with-server-and-upload-with-cli)

A small code sample that does the intial resumeable upload:

```
func StoreUpload(c appengine.Context, cn context.Context, contentType string, filename string, email string, origin string) (string, string, error) {
    uuid, err := UUID()

    if err != nil{
        return "", "", err
    }

    filename = uuid + filename[len(filename)-4:]

    tokenSource := google.AppEngineTokenSource(cn, storage.ScopeFullControl)

    token, err := tokenSource.Token()

    if err != nil{
        return "", "", err
    }

    metaBody := []byte("{ \"metadata\": { \"x-goog-meta-uploader\": \""+ email +"\" }}")

    req, err := http.NewRequest(
        "POST",
        fmt.Sprintf("https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/%s/o?uploadType=resumable&name=upload/%s", models.HYLIGHT_EXTERNAL_BUCKET, filename),
        bytes.NewReader(metaBody),
    )

    req.Header.Set("Authorization", "Bearer " + token.AccessToken)
    req.Header.Set("X-Upload-Content-Type", contentType)
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
    req.Header.Set("Content-Length", fmt.Sprint(len(metaBody)))
    req.Header.Set("Origin", origin)

    client := &http.Client{
        Transport:  &urlfetch.Transport{
            Context: c,
            Deadline: 20 * time.Second,
        },
    }

    res, err := client.Do(req)

    if err != nil{
        return "", "", err
    }

    return res.Header.Get("Location"), filename, err
}
```

The result in the google cloud bucket will have the correct mimetype of video/mp4 (that was decided by the browser) but still can't be viewed on the browser.

EDIT:

I've also tried using the chrome extension 'Postman' to upload a file after receiving an resumeable upload link but also its properties are lost when uploading to GCS, so it doesn't seem to be related to the JS side involved in uploading a file to GCS.

If I directly upload a folder with the video file in it using the 'upload folder' button on console.developer.google, the file's properties are retained.

Comment: Hi Rohan, looking into your code and reading the behavior, it looks like this might be an issue with the platform actually. Do you mind posting this on our issue tracker? https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list. If you could include this and a zipped minimal project to reproduce your upload, it would be super helpful (basically the code you have here, with the proper config file, in a zip). Thanks :)

Comment: Here we go: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12268. Looking forward to a fix!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the file is being corrupted when submitted to Google Cloud Storage via an HTML "input" form from the browser.  However, if the same URL is used to post the file via JavaScript, the file is not corrupted, which is very strange.

I am having the GCS team looking into the issue to see if there is a fix.

The full details, along with a workaround, are here:
https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12268

Thank you for working with me to get to the bottom of this!

Comment: The link to this issue is private and can't be viewed by the public